# single CIDs is referenced to multiple unicode encoding

Tags: pdf, unicode, encoding, fonts

While parsing a pdf file, I encounter a predefined CMap (UniCNS-UTF16-H, you can find it here http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmap.adobe/files/cmapresources_cns1-6.tar.z/download). When I look into it I found that single CIDs can be referenced into multiple unicodes.

My question is, what is the purpose of this ? How do I know to which unicode I should map my character ?

The header of cid2code.txt file says "There may be cases of single CIDs being referenced in multiple encoding points within a single CMap file. These cases are comma-delimited, within the same column." but it doesn't say why.

I had a look to the Technical Note #5080 "Adobe-CNS1-6 Character Collection for CID-Keyed Fonts", but I didn't find my answer. So if someone could point me the passage where this is explained and how to deal with it I would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unicode itself has [duplicate characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplicate_characters_in_Unicode).These duplicates should obviously map to the same glyph

EDIT : You also seem to have vertical/horizontal equivalents with v suffixed code points ex: [FE30](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fe30/index.htm) (VERTICAL TWO DOT) and [2025v](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2025/index.htm) (TWO DOT LEADER)

EDIT2 : Quoted from [technote 5094](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/font/pdfs/5094.CJK_CID.pdf)

> 1. The Hong Kong government also identified 84 pairs of duplicated characters that had existed in Hong Kong GCCS. The approach was
>      chosen to “unify” one instance of each pair (usually the second or
>      later appearance) with the character that had existed earlier. The
>      code points formerly occupied by the disappearing, “unified”
>      characters remain reserved for reasons of backward compatibility.
>      Again, the CIDs used to represent the two characters of the “unified” pairs 
>      remain in the character collection Adobe-CNS1 for reason of
>      backward compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there's a detailed passage anywhere that explicitly states *why* the CID specification allows mapping multiple CMap codes, but it does. Perhaps knowing a bit more about the design and use of CID fonts may help you understand the potential usefulness of this practice. I'd recommend having a read through [the CID specification](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/font/pdfs/5014.CIDFont_Spec.pdf).

Basically, CID was designed to be a collection of *glyph shapes*, with a CMap mechanism that can arbitrarily associate a code, or codes, with any of those shapes. They CIDs themselves are just glyphs, **not** Unicodes. The CMaps were purposely designed to be disconnected from the CID font data to allow easy updating and addition of mappings without changing the glyph data. So, for example, a CID font with Japan1-6 ordering can have numerous mappings (CMaps) for the collection of shapes, and there are many to choose from (particularly for Japanese!). And you can even invent your own mapping if you want...you just have to distribute the CMap part and make sure it fits with the ordering in question.

In any case: it kind of doesn't matter *why* this is possible: it **is** possible, and that is that. So if you are developing something that deals with CIDs and/or CMaps, you should be prepared to handle that case. It can and does happen, and if you're not prepared to deal with it, your code will eventually break.

And by the way: CID format is not unique in this regard. It is common practice in OpenType (TrueType) to do the same thing, and likely in other font formats as well.